# how can you change a column of numbers to a space separated list in bash

Tags: bash, command-line, sed, awk

How can i take the output of this command...

```
ps -ef | grep ^apache | grep /sbin/httpd | awk '{print $2}'
16779
16783
16784
16785
16786
16787
16788
16789
16790
16794
16795
16796
16797
16799
16800
16801
16802
16803
16804
16805
```

...so a single column of numbers... and transform those numbers into a single line of numbers separated by a " -p "... This would be used for the following...

```
lsof -p 16779 -p 16783 -p 16784 ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pipe into

```
sed 's/^/-p /' | tr '\n' ' '
```

Comment: The `{ print }` bit can be replaced by a `1` as that is the default block when matching a rule.

Comment: The `sed` bit could be `'s/^/-p /'`

Answer (score 2):

If you have it available, `pidof` would be more convenient:

```
lsof $(pidof apache | sed 's/^\| / -p /g')
```

Comment: You could simplify the pipeline considerably; see the many other answers. Generally combining `sed` and `awk` in the same pipeline can nearly always be avoided. `ps -ef | awk '/^apache/ && /\/sbin\/httpd/{ printf(" -p %i", $2 }`

Comment: I was copying the OPs command line, but I agree the other answers have that covered, I'll remove the bottom example.

Answer (score 1):

```
tmp="lsof "
for i in `ps -ef | awk '/^apache/ && /httpd/ {print $2}'`;
do
 tmp=${tmp}" -p "${i}" "; 
done
echo $tmp
```

Should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

You could pipe into `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { printf "lsof" } { printf " -p %s", $1 } END { printf "\n" }'
```

Result:

```
lsof -p 16779 -p 16783 -p 16784 -p 16785 -p 16786 -p 16787 -p 16788 -p 16789 -p 16790 -p 16794 -p 16795 -p 16796 -p 16797 -p 16799 -p 16800 -p 16801 -p 16802 -p 16803 -p 16804 -p 16805
```

Answer (score 1):

In a command substitution, the newlines from the pipeline will be converted to spaces.

```
pids=$( ps -ef | awk '/^apache/ && /\/sbin\/httpd/ {print $2}' ) )
```

Then a call to printf can be used to format the options for `lsof`. The format string is repeated as necessary for each argument contained in `pids`.

```
lsof $( printf "-p %s " $pids )
```

Answer (score 0):

**Add the following code to your one liner:**

```
awk '{print $0 " -p "}' | tr '\n' '  ' | awk -F " " '{print "lsof -p "  $0}'
```

**Final code :**

```
ps -ef | grep ^apache | grep /sbin/httpd | awk '{print $2}' | awk '{print $0 " -p "}' | tr '\n' '  ' | awk -F " " '{print "lsof -p "  $0}'
```